# mysql utf8_unicode_ci issue. Strange character ¿ appears

Tags: mysql, database

I have set my MySQL database to utf8 and my table and column as well. What is this strange character doing in my database field?

> ¿que ha sido de mi

That first character, the upside down questionmark. The above text is saved in my database field. Why is this happening? It is happening only in Spanish, I haven't seen it in other languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [normal part of the Spanish language](http://spanish.about.com/od/writtenspanish/f/inverted_punctuation.htm), so if it is indeed only happening for Spanish texts there's nothing wrong with your database.

Comment: Thanks for telling me i thought there was something wrong with the database:) Thanks again!